# Music program for Ubuntu that can export an album or list of songs into one MP3

Tags: linux, music, ubuntu, mp3

I am looking to take a music album on my computer, merge all the songs so that they play one after the other (preferably in the original order).

I would then possibly be able to modify the gap-length inbetween the songs while retaining a decent output quality.

Is there anything like this for Ubuntu/Linux that uses a graphical interface?

I have been recommended **Audacity**, and I have tried it for what I want, but it is rather tedious to take care of multiple albums.

Comment: if you want to play in-order, why don't just make a playlist and sort it whatever you want?

Answer (score 1):

[MP3Wrap](http://mp3wrap.sourceforge.net/) looks like it could do the merging of multiple MP3 files into one large MP3. I don't think it can 'tail' off the beginning and end of each individual track, so you might also have to use some bulk MP3 editor to do that. Audacity has a feature called 'chain' that looks like it might work